# Default property value is not getting displayed

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display a default value for a property since it is empty and i want to display something rather than nothing.

Here's my cshtml code:

```
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.id)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Previous id </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.oldId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category </td>
                    <td id="categoryId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.categoryId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date of creation </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dateCreation)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date of modification</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dateModify)</td>
                </tr>
                @* TODO: Return name of logged in user. *@
                <tr>
                    <td>User id</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.userId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zone</td>
                    <td id="zoneId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.zoneId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Equipment</td>
                    <td id="equipmentId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.equipmentId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Equipment task</td>
                    <td id="taskId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.taskId)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date revision</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dateRevision)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here are my properties:

```
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int? oldId { get; set; } = 0; 
        public int? categoryId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateCreation { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateModify { get; set; } = new DateTime();
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public int? zoneId { get; set; }
        public int? equipmentId { get; set; }
        public int? taskId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateRevision { get; set; } = new DateTime();
```

Anyone knows what the reason is that the default value is not getting displayed?

Comment: Will you include your controller code? and the full view? Thanks.

Comment: Which property are you expecting a "default value" to be displayed for? one of the date fields?  Note the ` = new DateTime();` just sets the _initial_ value, it does not define a "default" if the property is `null`. Ssomething else may be setting the value to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not use the DisplayFor method and just calling the variable directly like 
@Model.id

Answer (score -1):

The reason why they are not being displayed is that they are null!

What you are saying in your class is that some properties CAN be null, and if you don't assign them a value they are null. So you are not able to display null.

What you can do is use Null-Coalescing Operator. A good link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZpOrdTGUi4&t=85s

So

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.oldId ?? 0)</td>
```